# Getting the elements selected of a jlist into a string list

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a jlist which has some elements and works properly. Then I am trying to add the selected jlist elements to string list, but it wont show any results (no errors though). Whats wrong?

```
inal JList list = new JList(arraylist.toArray());
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, list, "Select", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

        String lstr = list.getSelectedValue().toString();
        List<String> tolist = Arrays.asList(lstr);

        System.out.println(tolist);
    }
};
```

**Updated:** ( Fixed)

```
                       final ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {
                       public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e) { 



                           String lstr = list.getSelectedValuesList().toString();
                           System.out.println(lstr);
                           List<String> tolist = Arrays.asList(lstr);
                           System.out.println(tolist);

                       }
                       };

                       list.addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
```

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null, list, "Select", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using multiple selections, why are you using getSelectedValue instead of getSelectedValues or (for JDK 7) getSelectedValuesList?

Answer (score 3):

Register your `ListSelectionListener` with your `JList` and after the anonymous inner class has been declared

```
ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
           // ...
    }
};
list.addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
```

Read: [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Comment: added  list.addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener); but it says listSelectionListener may not have been initialized. @Reimeus

Comment: Sounds as if you have a uninitialized local variable - can you post your attempted code?

Comment: It is the same. I simply added your line below public void. @Reimeus

Comment: Note to self: be explicit

Comment: Ok thanks this part works now, but I dont get why the elements selected are not stored in the array. I replaced  getSelectedValue with getSelectedValuesList and still nothing @Reimeus

Comment: Fixed it. added joptionpane below listener.